# Why does RouteParams.get() return the wrong result?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When I use `this._router.navigate( ['Page', { param: 'a/b' }] );` to navigate to a URL such has

`http://localhost:3000/page?param=a/b`

Angular will allow me to read the param with `this._routeParams.get('param')`. If I access the same url directly, it changes the URL to

`http://localhost:3000/page?param=a`

And `this._routeParams.get('param')` returns `a`.

What can I do so this works properly?

Comment: is look invalid parameter value by having `a/b` value? because router will obviously going to remove `/` from url while reading it(because generally we do separate our routes based on `/`(slash) & `.`(dot)).. I think you might get same impact with `.` value

Comment: It looks like this may be [a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7312).

Comment: If you are trying to send multiple values put them in object and send param as an object. Not sure why you send a/b.